# Magento Category Meta Robots

Tags: magento-1.9

On our category management page we have a dropdown field for Meta Robots.  I'm not sure if this is coming from a module or not, but it's currently empty.  I'd expect it to contain options for nofollow etc.  How can I populate this?  Is anybody familiar with it?

[image]

Thanks